# pip install askbot error - Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, django, askbot

I want to install askbot app (http://askbot.org/doc/install.html). But I encountered error during installation.

I've did below actions.

1) made virtual environment under ananconda (python 3.5.2 / ubuntu 14.04)

2) installed django 1.9.8

3) made django project myproject

4) modified settings.py to connect MariaDB

5) installed mysql client

```
# sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev 
# pip install mysqlclient
```

6) migrated

```
python manage.py migrate
```

7) registered app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myproject',
]
```

But when I try to install askbot as below, I found error.

```
(envask)root@localhost:~/vikander# pip install askbot
Collecting askbot
  Downloading askbot-0.10.0.tar.gz (8.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 8.6MB 116kB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-vppvsnhk/askbot/setup.py", line 135
       **************************************************************"""
                                                                    ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-vppvsnhk/askbot/
```

Is this python version problem? Is there no way to install askbot under python 3.x envirionment? Thanks in advnace.

Comment: I would guess the error it states ("SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'") means you've ended up with a python 2.x script being run as python 3.

Comment: So I have to install askbot under python 2.x envirionment? Thanks your comment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Askbot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/askbot/0.7.56) is not compatible with python 3, which changes `print` from a statement like so:

```
print `Hello World`
```

into a function:

```
print('Hello world')
```

More about this change [here](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function)

You'll need to find an alternative, or push a fix to the Askbot repo.

Comment: I didn't check the site https://pypi.python.org/pypi/askbot/0.7.56. I just find installation info in http://askbot.org/doc/install.html. It was a basic problem as you mention. Thanks for your answer.